# Setting Outgoing Emails Servers in Odoo

Tags: odoo

I'm trying to set-up outgoing email server in Odoo for my Organization.
For doing so the system request for username and password along with server details,
Now we have around 15 users in Odoo.
Do we need to enter all usernames individually?

Answer (score 0):

Odoo is not a mail server.

You have to configure with your any of your official mail accounts (gmail/outlook/any other official mail service you have for your office). odoo will use those to send mail.

**Description**:  A description for the outgoing mail server.

**SMTP server**:  The pointer to the SMTP of your server, ex.  smtp.gmail.com .

**SMTP port**:  The port of your SMTP server, ex. 465 for Gmail.

**Connection security**:  You should choose SSL/TLS for Gmail.

**Username**:  Your e-mail account, like: youremail@gmail.com

**Password**:   Password of your e-mail account.

Answer (score 0):

SMTP Server :- smtp.gmail.com

SMTP Port :- 465

Connection Security :- SSL/TLS

Username :- Your mail account

Password:- Password of your email account

Answer (score 0):

The following fields are needed to configure the mail server.

**Description :->**  A description of the Outgoing mail server

**Priority :->** Priority of your outgoing mail server. Low priority mail servers are used first and mostly.

**SMTP Server :->** The server SMTP e.g,  zsmtp.hybridzimbra.com(for Thunderbird)

**SMTP Port :->** The SMTP port of your server e.g, 465 (for Thunderbird)

**Connection Security :->** Security to be used like TLS(STARTTLS) or SSL/TLS. Use  SSL/TLS for Thunderbird

**Username :->** Your e-mail account.

**Password:->** The password of your e-mail account.

I think the following document should help you out.
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/applications/general/email_communication/email_servers.html